# Codeigniter db select where as an array

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this code i need to use to get results from a database, I'm on codeigniter. This is how the query looks like,

```
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('broadcast_id', $bid);
        $query = $this->db->get('ih_noticeboard');
        $result = $query->result();
        if($query->num_rows() < 1){
            $data = "no feed ";
        }else{
            $data = $result;
        }
```

the `$bid` in the where clause is got from this code,

```
    $this->db->select('broadcast_id');
    $this->db->where('broadcast_subscribers', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('ih_broadcastors    ');
    if($query->num_rows() < 1){
        $data = "user not subscribed to any broadcasting";
    }else{
        $ress = $query->result();
        foreach ($ress as $row){
            $bid = $row->broadcast_id;
        }`
```

Now the select uses only one $bid, how can I use the $bid as an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it be better to have one query to get the feeds?

```
$this->db->select("ih_noticeboard.*");
$this->db->from("ih_noticeboard");
$this->db->join("ih_broadcastors", "ih_noticeboard.broadcast_id = ih_broadcasters.broadcast_id");
$this->db->where("ih_broadcastors.broadcast_subscribers", $id);
$result->db->get()->result();
```

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple .
just use $this->db->where_in('broadcast_id', $bid);

instead if $this->db->where('broadcast_id', $bid);

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to select in the table where

> name='jane' and broadcast_id=2 #as an example

```
        $bid=array(
           'name'=>'jane',
           'broadcast_id'=>'2'
                  ) 

        $this->db->where($bid);
        $this->db->from($table_name);
        $query = $this->db->get()->result_array();
        return $query;
```

Please notice that the *$bid* as array must be formated to suite the next **database table** to be queried. You can do this using **foreach loop** E.g

```
   foreach ($ress as $row){
        $bid = array(
             'name'=>$row['name'],
             'broadcast_id'=>$row['id']
         );
    }
```